# stop it scrolling to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this bit of code, it limits the Li's to 15 of them and there is a button what shows 15 more Li's but it scrolls the page to the top what i don't want i can't stop it. can you help?

```
    $(window).load(function(){
    var vis = 15;

    $('li').slice(vis).hide();
    var $more = $('<a href="#">test</a>')
        $more.click(function () {
        $('li:hidden').slice(0, vis).show();        

    if($('li:hidden').length == 0)
        $more.hide();
    });
    $('ul').after($more);});
```

Comment: I see nothing in this pretty script scrolling the page. Are you sure your ul isn't in an enclosing div with an event handler ?

Comment: Clicking the “more” link will cause the page to jump to the top because the browser thinks you’re trying to navigate to a page anchor.

Slash197’s answer below will work as it stops the default action of the link.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't think about that (I never use links for things that are not links). Well seen.

Comment: yeah it works great. :) yeah dystroy i thought that as well but i just couldn't stop it happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var vis = 15;

    $('li').slice(vis).hide();
    var $more = $('<a href="#">test</a>')
        $more.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('li:hidden').slice(0, vis).show();        

    if($('li:hidden').length == 0)
        $more.hide();
    });
    $('ul').after($more);});
```